# Reading floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

I am trying reading floating point numbers (command line input). Is this the right way?

```
sscanf(argv[i], "%f", &float)
```

Comment: Well, is it? If you compile and run it, what happens?

Comment: `float` is a reserved word in C that you cannot use as a variable name.

Comment: its not letting me post my code sry

Comment: @Kerrek i used a variable float f, it should have been &f

Comment: @Chris i run in my shell window it doesn't print out the value

Answer (score 2):

Using `sscanf()` with an element of `argv` is one way to extract a `float` from a command line *argument*. You should also check the return value to see if a `float` was actually extracted from the string and stored into your variable.

Perhaps a better way is using `strtod()`, since you can perform better validation with it's second argument. You can use that pointer to check that the last character used in the conversion was the last character in the string. ie. You could check that `"3.5abc"` contained a valid float, but the whole string wasn't one single valid float.

If what you mean by *command line input* is reading input from `stdin`, then that has nothing to do with `argv` and you should instead be using `scanf()` or `fgets()` + `strtod()`.

Note that there's also the function `atof` which is essentially a version of `strtod` that doesn't give you the extra error checking capability. From the man pages it's just: `strtod(nptr, (char **) NULL);`. C99 also provides the function `strtof()`, which returns a `float` instead of a `double`. You can assign a `double` to a `float` and have it implicitly converted, so don't think that using `strtod()` will cause a problem.